# how can i use an android tablet that I am locked out of

Tags: linux, tablet

I was given a cheap, basic, tablet a few months ago, third hand, via my sister who couldn't get on with it.  I tried it a bit then put it to one side to look at another time. When i came back to it (several months later) it asked for a password. I don't remember there being one, and nor does my sister so I'm stuck.  I know there normally ways to do factory resets in a state like this I've tried all of them, nothing works.  The tablet has no markings so I can't even look up that way.  I hate the idea of throwing it away, I'd like to use it as a monitor, or install a linux distro on it, but I've no idea how without the password. if anyone has any suggestion I'd be grateful

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to access the recovery menu or similar and perform a factory reset by pressing and holding some button combination as the tablet first starts.  On most Nexus devices, for example, it's done by holding both volume buttons and the power button.

Answer (score 0):

See [how-to-factory-reset-your-android-tablet](http://www.howtogeek.com/130611/how-to-factory-reset-your-android-phone-or-tablet-when-it-wont-boot/).

This page states:

> Press and hold the correct keys to boot the device into recovery mode. This will vary from device to device. Here are some examples:
>
> - Nexus 7: Volume Up + Volume Down + Power
> - Samsung Galaxy S3: Volume Up + Home + Power
> - Motorola Droid X: Home + Power
> - Devices With Camera Buttons: Volume Up + Camera
>
> Similar devices will likely use similar key combinations. For example, the Nexus 4 also uses Volume Up + Volume Down + Power.
>
> If your device isn’t on this list and none of the above methods work, do a Google search for the name of your device and “recovery mode” – or look in the device’s manual or support pages.
>
> Release the buttons when the device powered on. You’ll see an image of an Android lying on its back with its chest open and its internals revealed.

Maybe superfluous, but you'll wipe all data from the device when you reset it to system defaults.